# Parsing file into Parent/ Child format for a JSON file

Tags: python, json, genetics

I would like some help/ advice on how to parse this file for [Gene ontology (.obo)](http://geneontology.org/ontology/go-basic.obo)

I am working to create a visualisation in D3, and need to create a "tree" file, in the JSON format -

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "description": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytic",
   "description": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "description": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Agglomer", "description": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "Communit", "description": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "Hierarch", "description": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdg", "description": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    }, etc..
```

This format seems fairly easy to replicate in a dictionary in python, with 3 fields for each entry: name, description, and children[].

My probelm here is actually HOW to extract the data. The file linked above has "objects" structured as:

```
[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764]
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution
```

Where I will need the id, is_a and name fields. I have tried using python to parse this, but I cant seem to find a way to locate each object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple way to parse the objects in your '.obo' file. It saves the object data into a `dict` with the `id` as the key and the `name` and `is_a` data saved in a list. Then it pretty-prints it using the standard `json` module's `.dumps` function.

For testing purposes, I used a truncated version of the file in your link that only includes up to `id: GO:0000006`.

This code ignores any objects that contain the `is_obsolete` field. It also removes the description info from the `is_a` fields; I figured you probably wanted that, but it's easy enough to disable that functionality.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Parse object data from a .obo file

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/32989776/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.10.07
'''

from __future__ import print_function, division

import json
from collections import defaultdict

fname = "go-basic.obo"
term_head = "[Term]"

#Keep the desired object data here
all_objects = {}

def add_object(d):
    #print(json.dumps(d, indent = 4) + '\n')
    #Ignore obsolete objects
    if "is_obsolete" in d:
        return

    #Gather desired data into a single list,
    # and store it in the main all_objects dict
    key = d["id"][0]
    is_a = d["is_a"]
    #Remove the next line if you want to keep the is_a description info
    is_a = [s.partition(' ! ')[0] for s in is_a]
    all_objects[key] = d["name"] + is_a


#A temporary dict to hold object data
current = defaultdict(list)

with open(fname) as f:
    #Skip header data
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == term_head:
            break

    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line:
            #ignore blank lines
            continue
        if line == term_head:
            #end of term
            add_object(current)
            current = defaultdict(list)
        else:
            #accumulate object data into current
            key, _, val = line.partition(": ")
            current[key].append(val)

if current:
    add_object(current)    

print("\nall_objects =")
print(json.dumps(all_objects, indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
```

**output**

```
all_objects =
{
    "GO:0000001": [
        "mitochondrion inheritance", 
        "GO:0048308", 
        "GO:0048311"
    ], 
    "GO:0000002": [
        "mitochondrial genome maintenance", 
        "GO:0007005"
    ], 
    "GO:0000003": [
        "reproduction", 
        "GO:0008150"
    ], 
    "GO:0000006": [
        "high-affinity zinc uptake transmembrane transporter activity", 
        "GO:0005385"
    ]
}
```